Getting the value of the TypeDiscriminator value in JsonPolymorphic
I parse a big json file with JsonPolymorphic of System.Text.Json. The json is a audit log and is generated by a third party and I have no control over it. I am only interested in a small part of the file.
I use the Operation property of the json as type discriminator I set IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators to true so all objects I am not interested in are put into the base class. Since I have no control, over the json I could happen that a new Operation is generated. I like to check against a list of know Operations if this is unknown. But when add a Operation to my base type, it is always null.
Is there a way to get the Type Discriminator property value for values that are not matching any derived type?

A very similar issue, Questions about JsonSerializer.Deserialize #83704, was closed by MSFT as not planned.  I'm happy to be proven wrong, but apparently MSFT doesn't want you to get access to the type discriminator values.  You may need to abandon their builtin polymorphism support and go back to writing your own converter.
